# JointJS: Change link arrows to circle

Tags: javascript, svg, jointjs

I'm using [jointJS](http://jointjs.com) for creating diagrams. The library creates links thats when hovering, arrows are displayed for moving/reconnecting them.
I would like to change them to small circles with another color.

As the arrows are the default design, I don't know which code I should show - as exactly this is my problem: How can I change a default setting/SVG layout?

Comment: This question is too broad. Please include some code to illustrate your problem

Comment: As the arrows are the default design, I don't know which code I should show - as exactly this is my problem: How can I change a default setting/SVG layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have to work with `joint.dia.Link` class.

It has inner property called arrowheadMarkup which obviously is responsible for represnting arrowheads markup (`line 5828 @ joint.js v0.9.5`)

```
    arrowheadMarkup: [
      '<g class="marker-arrowhead-group marker-arrowhead-group-<%= end %>">',
      '<path class="marker-arrowhead" end="<%= end %>" d="M 26 0 L 0 13 L 26 26 z" />',
      '</g>'
    ].join('')
```

Try to replace path.marker-arrowhead with any SVG code you want to see as an arrowhead in your child class.

Probably resulting code will look smth like this:

```
var myPrettyLink = joint.dia.Link.extend({
    ...
    arrowheadMarkup: [
      '<g class="marker-arrowhead-group marker-arrowhead-group-<%= end %>">',
      '<circle class="marker-arrowhead" cx="20" cy="20" r="15"></circle>',
      '</g>'
    ].join('')
    ...
});
```

Comment: Where do I have to define this? I defined `defaultLink: new joint.dia.Link({})` in `var paper = new joint.dia.Paper()`

Comment: ok, so you need to create new custom link which inherits from `joint.dia.Link`

somewhere in beginning of your code define new link
`var customLink = joint.dia.Link.extend({
arrowheadMarkup: [
'<g class="marker-arrowhead-group marker-arrowhead-group-<%= end %>">',
'<circle class="marker-arrowhead" cx="20" cy="20" r="15"></circle>',
'</g>'
].join('')
})`

Comment: Thanks. It works. Do you know how to avoid different sizes? If the link is very short, the icons get smaller. I need a fixed size.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I guess you should extend Link with an option 
`{ shortLinkLength: 0 }`

Comment: This option shows the normal (non-short) link minimal length (100 by default). All links with length lesser than provided will be treated as a short links and thus their icons will be scaled.

Answer (score 3):

I have redefined the default link "arrowhead" in my current project. Here is the graph code:

```
var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
    el: $('#paper'),
    perpendicularLinks: true,
    gridSize: 1,
    model: graph,
    //snapLinks: { radius: 5 },
    defaultLink: new joint.shapes.devs.Link({
        attrs: {
            '.marker-target': {
                d: arrowheadShape
            }
        }
    })
});
```

Then this is the variable that holds the actual shape definition:

```
var arrowheadShape = 'M 10 0 L 0 5 L 10 10 z';
```

In this case I merely sized up the default triangle. You could replace this with any arbitrary SVG path you wanted.

ON EDIT: I believe I've misread your question. My approach redefines the default shape of the link's head, not the other icon that appears when you're dragging the end of a link around. My bad, sorry.